How to get the token account in Solana?
I am trying to get token account for this.
#[account(mut)]
    pub nft_info: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

I used getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(), but there is an error.
Error: AnchorError caused by account: nft_info. Error Code: AccountNotInitialized. Error Number: 3012. Error Message: The program expected this account to be already initialized. 

Please help me this.
Additionally, when the NFT minted, the token account is generated, isn't it?
Fully understanding about the token account.

Anchor expects all typed accounts Account<'info, T> to be initialized when being passed in.
In your case, nft_info is probably not defined.
You can initialize it using anchor constraints, if it's an ATA, the code will be
#[account(
  init,
  associated_token::mint = <target_account>,
  associated_token::authority = <target_account>,
  associated_token::token_program = <target_account>
)]
pub nft_info: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,


Thank you for your reply.
Could you explain more detail?
I need to account information of the NFT in Solana Anchor program to update the NFT metadata.
Could you please more detail plz?

The error you are facing indicates you are passing a non initialized token account. Can you check on this

NFT minting does not automatically create the token account. You must manually create the account.
Use getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(mint, owner) to compute the Associated Token Account (ATA) address.
Check if the token account exists. If not, create it using createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction.

But in console, I can see the token account of the NFT and I can check it on solscan.
For example, the NFT id that I wanna get the token account is "2e9fSiMNFL1iv6tcSLZuMpDnqx2RVYkvRnLLhqgNYet5" and the token account that get from the getAssociatedTokenAddressSync() medhod is "GojcyNqjLoWK2KB9PVfu6Rdvx95V1uqFz6LBT4KB8iRE" and I can see it on solscan.
Could you please explain more detail?

You can check it in solana explorer.
https://explorer.solana.com/address/GojcyNqjLoWK2KB9PVfu6Rdvx95V1uqFz6LBT4KB8iRE
