Trouble with nft_info Account in Solana Anchor Test Code
I’m new to Solana development, and I’m having trouble writing test code for my program. Specifically, I can’t seem to properly initialize and use the nft_info account.
Here’s part of my Rust code:
#[account(mut)]
pub nft_info: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

And here’s how I try to get the token account in my client-side code:
const nftMintAddress = new PublicKey(
    "2e9fSiMNFL1iv6tcSLZuMpDnqx2RVYkvRnLLhqgNYet5"
);
const nftTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
    nftMintAddress,
    user
);

await program.methods
    .test(value)
    .accounts({
        user: user,
        nftInfo: nftTokenAccount,
        systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
    })
    .rpc();

However, when I run this, I get the following error:
Error: AnchorError caused by account: nft_info. Error Code: AccountNotInitialized. Error Number: 3012. Error Message: The program expected this account to be already initialized.

I’m not sure how to fix this. It seems like my nft_info account isn’t properly initialized before it’s used. How can I ensure the token account is correctly initialized, or am I missing something in how I set it up?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

You'd already asked this question here -> https://solana.stackexchange.com/q/18267/1708

The anchor error indicates that you are trying to use an account, nftInfo that doesn't exist yet.
Fetching the token accounts for the mint you shared, I only found one -> https://explorer.solana.com/address/GojcyNqjLoWK2KB9PVfu6Rdvx95V1uqFz6LBT4KB8iRE?cluster=devnet
Some areas you could use to debug,

Make sure that you are running your program in the correct cluster. Perhaps you haven't updated your Anchor.toml file to point to devnet

[provider]
cluster = "devnet"
wallet = "~/.config/solana/id.json"


Make sure that the user address matches is correctly set. Perhaps you are using an anchor provider that isn't the mint authority of the token account, i.e chSDLoUSFfBer3G8UZUQGRzd2gjS137UQwFJX6RsfhL

